# Monitoring RESTful API performance over time

Tags: performance, rest, jenkins, monitoring

I'm currently investigating ways in which I can monitor releases of our RESTful API web application to spot when end point performance degrades from a previous release.

What we were finding is that if we tweak the underlying data access code (say, by adding a new parameter), we'd only find out if performance nose-dived once we released to production. I thought that it we run some timings on the end points after every release to staging (being the environment before production, and with production data), then we'd be alerted earlier. Ideally I want to automate this though, so it's not another manual step in the release process.

So far I've configured an instance of Jenkins to run http://www.sitespeed.io/ against various end points, and plot the response times in a graph (using a Jenkins plot plugin). By running the Jenkins projects after each staging release, the graph plots the response times over time.

The major drawback of this is that it won't alert us if the performance differs from the previous release: we'd manually need to eyeball the graph. Ideally I'd want to say that if the new response time is %5 over the last one, send an email.

So my question is, can anyone think of a way to do this with Jenkins, or know of any other tool that can monitor non-production URLs over time?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Have you looked at JMeter?

Comment: I have, but it doesn't track results over multiple runs (at least from what I can tell)